# How would voltage change in time in an electrolytic solution?

Tags: time, voltage

I'm building a teaching model and a question came up that isn't very clear to me. I would like some help.

The voltage of a sphere (~5 cm in diameter) uniformly charged, in this case positively as in the figure below, decays exponentially as a function of distance (d) like that of a point charge, according to the equation: $V(d)=KQ/d$.
[image]

- How would $V(d)$ behave if the charged sphere is immersed in an electrolyte solution (NaCl ~280 mM)? In this case, what equation describes $V(d)$?
- Assuming that $V(d)$ also decays exponentially (in the case of the sphere immersed in an electrolyte solution), how would the voltage behave as a function of time, $V(t)$, at a given distance (d) if the charge on the sphere were instantaneously changed from positive to negative? The figure below helps to visualize this issue. In this case, what equation describes $V(t)$?
  [image]

Comment: $1/d$ is not called exponential decay. Exponential decay would be $e^{-kd}$.

Comment: @Vander I have made some edits to your question. Also next time please consider using Mathjax for mathematical equations.

Comment: See [Debye length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_length).